# Options for doctrine:generate-module in Symfony

Tags: symfony1, model, code-generation

Is there any drawback in Symfony when generating modules without the `--non-verbose-templates` option?

I can only see that whenever you change the model, you also have to change the `_form` partial by hand.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The difference is that verbose-templates expands the form. For example, in a **non-verbose-template** the output is:

```
//..
<?php echo $form ?>
//..
```

and in a **verbose-template**:

```
//...
<tr>
  <td><?php echo $form['field_1']->renderLabel() ?></td>
  <td><?php echo $form['field_1']->renderError() ?></td>
  //etc..
</tr>
//etc.
//...
```

Comment: Yeah, I know what the actual result is. My question is if this behaviour has any collateral consequences apart from having to edit the template by hand in future changes.

Comment: Using the verbose-template is easiest if want to apply a design, for example change all <tr><td> for <div> or align in a differnt way without touching symfony's code. Using non-verbose-templates you can also do it by creating a custom decorator (it's a little more difficult) and setting it to the *Form (and also have the advantage that if you change your model you don't have to touch the view) ... So, if all of your forms are having the same design i would go for creating a decorator. You can see ttp://bit.ly/ftCenz for an example.